# Evaluate: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{2^{n-2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I go about finding the sum of this series? 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{2^{n-2}}$$

Comment: Try (really: **try** ) the n-th root test...

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{2^{n-2}}$ ?

Comment: @experimentX yeah that's what i mean

Comment: differentiate and put $x=\frac{1}{2}$ down below.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: for $|x|<1$, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x},$$ so $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=???$$ and $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}=???$$

---

> Differentiate twice to get $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3},$$ and put $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I"m sorry, I don't understand how this helps edit: nvm thanks a lot

Comment: To get it clear: Since the geometric series is absolutely convergent (if |x|<1), one can change the order of differentiation and summation?

Comment: @LeoSti: There are various ways to look at this, but yes, it's because a power series is uniformly convergent on $[-r+\varepsilon,r-\varepsilon]$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, where $r$ is the radius of convergence. See Theorem 8.1 in Baby Rudin.